# how to filter a multilevel menu with a search input

Tags: javascript, multi-level

The difficulty is that the menu has many levels(like the menu in matrix-admin),and every level is large; how should i filter filter the menu on the basis of the value of the search input.

and the output should be like this:(http://www.jqueryrain.com/?lEMFOjZ1)
and my html is like this:

```
<ul>
<li>xxx</li>
<li>
   <a>xxx</a>
   <ul>
      <li>
           <a>xxx</a>
           <ul>
                <li>
                   <a>xxx</a>
                   <ul></ul>
                </li>
           </ul>
      </li>
      <li>xxxx</li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Share your html....!!

Comment: sorry... ,I have appended the thml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [*Demo Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMYEm/)

```
$("li").each(function () {
    if (filter == "") {
        $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
        $(this).fadeIn();
    } else if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
        $(this).fadeOut();
    } else {
        $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

`Onkeypress` event the menu will be filtered.... The parent `li` will be visible, if you try find the child `li`...

Comment: it is simple... how should i deal with if one of the deeped hireachy menu is fillted

Comment: @user3796331 No one can't explain more clear than this

Comment: How to show/hide particular ul/li if used css and active etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery for this.

```
document.querySelector("#filter").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var filter = this.value;
  var count = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(li) {
    if (filter == "") {
      li.style["display"] = "list-item";
    } else if (!li.textContent.match(filter)) {
      li.style["display"] = "none";
    } else {
      li.style["display"] = "list-item";
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gfe9y5o2/

Comment: How to use it on particular div or ul using id? its searching whole li on the page.

Comment: just add a class to your `<ul>` and add this to the `document.querySelectorAll`

Here is an example: [https://jsfiddle.net/gfe9y5o2/42/](https://jsfiddle.net/gfe9y5o2/42/)